# Can I convert a 3-D plot into a 2-D plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, physics

I am studying the Landau Free Energy Equation. First of all the plot displayed only shown negative range. can i show the positive range too? (y-axes). Then, can I turn this plot into 2-D Plot?

```
α= 1;
β= 1;
Tmp = 0.1316;
ρ= 0.01;
T = -2;

FreeEnergy = 
  1/2*(T - 1)*P^2 + 1/4*P^4 + (1/2*α^2*β*M^2*(T - Tmp)) + 
  1/4 α^2*(β)*(M^4) + 1/2*(ρ*(P^2)*(M^2))

Plot3D[FreeEnergy, {M, -2.05216, 2.05217}, {P, -2.35669, 2.35669}]
```

[image]

#### Update

This what I want. It should be extended to the positive side. Maybe I should minimize the equation first?

[image]

After use `ViewPoint-> {-Infinity,0,0}` i get this but still not quite right (because the orange part is showing and both left and right should extend to positive side like above picture).

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by turning it into a 2D plot? Do you want a slice through it? A projection? A density plot? A contour plot? Also, your function doesn't take any positive values in the domain you've passed to `Plot3D`. You can set the displayed range manually with `PlotRange` though.

Comment: `ContourPlot[FreeEnergy, {M, -2.05216, 2.05217}, {P, -2.35669, 
  2.35669}]` and `DensityPlot[FreeEnergy, {M, -2.05216, 2.05217}, {P, -2.35669, 
  2.35669}]` are two examples of 2D plots of the 3D data

Comment: from front-view like the arrow is showing in the picture that i just edit. @JasonB

Comment: from the front-view. in the documentation, this is under what category? @MartinBüttner

Comment: @Nabil Something like using the `ViewPoint -> {-Infinity, 0, 0}` option?

Comment: yes that will do thank you @MartinBüttner

Comment: Either `Plot[Evaluate[FreeEnergy /. M -> 0], {P, -2.35669, 2.35669}]` or `Plot[Evaluate[FreeEnergy /. P -> 0], {M, -2.05216, 2.05217}]`.

Comment: The reason you're not seeing any positive values in the graph is because the function doesn't take any positive values for the range you're plotting. Any reason you're not doing something like `Plot3D[FreeEnergy, {M, -3, 3}, {P, -3, 3}]` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After help from everybody. this question has been resolved. we can do as follows;

```
α= 1;
β= 1;
tmp = 0.1316;
ρ= 0.01;
t = -2;

fe[m_, p_] := 
 1/2*(t - 1)*p^2 + 1/4*p^4 + (1/2*α^2*β*m^2*(t - tmp)) + 
  1/4 α^2*(β)*(m^4) + 1/2*(ρ*(p^2)*(m^2))

Show[SliceContourPlot3D[
  z - fe[m, p], {z == -3}, {m, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}, {z, -6, 6}], 
 SliceContourPlot3D[-z, 
  z == fe[m, p], {m, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}, {z, -6, 6}]]
```

[image: Top view]

[image: Side view]

```
Plot[Evaluate[FreeEnergy /. P -> 0], {M, -3, 3}]
```

[image: 2-D]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is not just `ContourPlot`. Just minor changes:

```
α = 1;
β = 1;
tmp = 0.1316;
ρ = 0.01;
t = -2;

fe[m_, p_] := 
 1/2*(t - 1)*p^2 + 1/4*p^4 + (1/2*α^2*β*m^2*(t - tmp)) + 
  1/4 α^2*(β)*(m^4) + 1/2*(ρ*(p^2)*(m^2))
```

Now,

```
Show[SliceContourPlot3D[
  z - fe[m, p], {z == -4}, {m, -2.05216, 2.05217}, {p, -2.35669, 
   2.35669}, {z, -5, 0}], 
 SliceContourPlot3D[-z, 
  z == fe[m, p], {m, -2.05216, 2.05217}, {p, -2.35669, 
   2.35669}, {z, -5, 0}]]
```

[image]

Comment: there is 4 bowl-like in the 3-D graph which shows the minimum point. how can we know the 4 minimum points of the graph? @ubpdqn

Answer (score 3):

One or both of the following plots may be what you looking for.

```
α = 1;
β = 1;
Tmp = 0.1316;
ρ = 0.01;
T = -2;

FreeEnergy = 
  1/2*(T - 1)*P^2 + 
   1/4*P^4 + (1/2*α^2*β*M^2*(T - Tmp)) + 
   1/4 α^2*(β)*(M^4) + 1/2*(ρ*(P^2)*(M^2));

Plot[Evaluate[FreeEnergy /. M -> 0], {P, -2.35669, 2.35669}]
```

[image: plot1]

```
Plot[Evaluate[FreeEnergy /. P -> 0], {M, -2.05216, 2.05217}]
```

[image: plot2]